# How to output a randomly chosen word and scramble the same word from a text file java

Tags: java

Below is the output that I have. I would like my scrambled word below to be the same as my random word. Right now its printing two different words from the text file and I want it to be the same, except one scrambled and the other regular. Below is my code.

[image]

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ScrambleWords {

    private static Scanner file;
    private static List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    private static List<Character> characters = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void openFile() {

        try {
            file = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File Not Found");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("IOException");
        }
    }

    public static String randomWord() {

        Random r = new Random();

        while(file.hasNext()) {
            words.add(file.next());
        }

        Collections.shuffle(words);
        String randomWord = words.get(r.nextInt(words.size()));

        return randomWord;
    }

    public static String readScramble(String randomWord) {

        for(char ch : randomWord.toCharArray()) {
            characters.add(ch);
        }

        Collections.shuffle(characters);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(char ch: characters) { 
            sb.append(ch);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        openFile();

        String scramble = readScramble(randomWord());
        System.out.println("Scramble Word is: " + scramble);

        String random = randomWord();
        System.out.println("Random Word is: " + random);

    }

}
```

Comment: please remeber to close that scanner

Answer (score 2):

You're getting two different instances of random word. Modify your code to look like this:

```
 openFile();

    String word = randomWord();
    String scramble = readScramble(word);
    System.out.println("Scramble Word is: " + scramble);

    String random = word;
    System.out.println("Random Word is: " + random);
```

Comment: For sure @eric24g. If I answered your question, please mark as resolved for other devs on the forum.

Comment: Im sorry, where do I mark as resolved. Im new to this. Thank You. @andrewdleach

Comment: No worries. Click the opaque checkmark next to the answer. It will turn green

Answer (score 1):

Change your main method:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    openFile();

    String word = randomWord();

    String scramble = readScramble(word);
    System.out.println("Scramble Word is: " + scramble);

    System.out.println("Random Word is: " + word);

}
```

By the way, maybe you should post this code on the code review stack exchange.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `randomWord()` twice, thereby generating two random words. By definition of "random", you cannot expect the same word twice. Change you main method to

```
String w = randomWord();
```

then print `w` and its scramled version.